# Wine: do not check for Mono installation

Tags: wine

I want to use wine without Mono, as I only want to run pure win32 applications, no .NET stuff at all. Is there a way to skip the mono check when configuring a (new) Wineprefix?

[image]

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334144/wine-do-not-check-for-gecko-installation/334299

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either build Wine without Mono support (`--disable-mscoree`) or add an override to disable loading of `mscoree.dll` using `winecfg`.

To avoid the initial dialog upon new wineprefix creation you could try the following:

```
WINEPREFIX=$(pwd)/my_new_prefix WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree=d wineboot
```

(after creation make the setting permanent using `winecfg`)

The dialog is shown because the creation of new wineprefix triggers `DllRegisterServer` of `mscoree` which in turn tries to install missing Mono runtime if not already done.