# What can I remove from a standard Wine wineprefix/bottle/configuration?

Tags: wine

I let `wine` create a new wineprefix by setting the directory and running `winecfg` and the resulting folder is over 500 MB. Does it need to be this large or are there folders that I can remove from the standard install to slim it down after it is created and populated? Which folders/files?

Answer (score 1):

Here are directories that can be deleted if you don't need mono or gecko:

- `wineprofile/drive_c/windows/Installer` (145 mb)
- `wineprofile/drive_c/windows/mono` (126 mb)
- `wineprofile/drive_c/windows/system32/gecko/2.47` (103 mb)
- `wineprofile/drive_c/windows/syswow64/gecko/2.47` (96 mb)
- `wineprofile/drive_c/windows/Microsoft.NET` (5 mb)

total: 475 mb.

Note that the `2.47` in the gecko paths will change with the version number.

Those directories contain, as far as I understand, the files from the [wine mono](https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono) and [wine gecko](https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko) installations. For whatever reason wine needs those files in each wineprofile. So if you have 10 wineprofiles then you have 10 times of those 475 mb on your harddisk.

I have tested this on one system only with one windows application only. My system is arch linux updated as of januar 2017.

Here are the wine version numbers:

```
$ pacman -Q wine wine-mono wine_gecko 
wine 2.0rc3-1
wine-mono 4.6.4-1
wine_gecko 2.47-1
```

The windows application is fcpro ([freecell pro](http://www.solitairelaboratory.com/fcpro.html)). A freecell implementation with some features I have not found on any other freecell implementation. It is likely that fcpro does not use any mono or gecko features.

Here is how I tested:

- run command:

  ```
  WINEPREFIX=yesmonogecko wine fcpro
  ```

  wineprofile gets created with mono and gecko installed. size is about 500 mb.
- run command:

  ```
  WINEPREFIX=nomonogecko WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree=d;mshtml=d wine fcpro
  ```

  wineprofile gets created without mono and gecko installed. size is about 40 mb. see links below for more details.
- compare `yesmonogecko` to `nomonogecko`.
- delete the extra directories in `yesmonogecko`.
- run again command:

  ```
  WINEPREFIX=yesmonogecko wine fcpro
  ```

  see that everything works fine.

See also:

- [Wine: do not check for Mono installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191608/wine-do-not-check-for-mono-installation)
- [Wine: do not check for Gecko installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334144/wine-do-not-check-for-gecko-installation)