# Wine: do not check for Gecko installation

Tags: wine

I want to use wine without Gecko, as I only want to run simple applications, no HTML stuff at all. Is there a way to skip the gecko check when configuring a (new) Wineprefix?

Related: [Wine: do not check for Mono installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191608/wine-do-not-check-for-mono-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `mshtml` to prevent wine from installing gecko.

```
WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mshtml=d wine somewineapp
```

To prevent both mono and gecko:

```
WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree=d;mshtml=d wine somewineapp
```

And to keep all other possibly existing `WINEDLLOVERRIDES`:

```
WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree=d;mshtml=d;$WINEDLLOVERRIDES wine somewineapp
```

See also:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/323437/how-to-prevent-wine-from-adding-file-associations
- [What can I remove from a standard Wine wineprefix/bottle/configuration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312125/what-can-i-remove-from-a-standard-wine-wineprefix-bottle-configuration/334298)